# ARC error when compiling

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to compile using the LLVM GCC 4.0 compiler, and I get this error in multiple of my .m files: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
I've tried using -fno-objc-arc as a compiler flag but that returns the error: Unrecognized command line option "-fno-objc-arc".

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 45):

Simply remove all calls to `-release`. You're not allowed to call `-release` under ARC because the compiler will insert all the necessary `retain`/`release` calls for you. Read more about ARC [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

The other way is to use the conversion tool, and Xcode can convert your project to ARC (including removing these calls) for you:
[image]

To disable ARC entirely, change your build settings:
[image]

However I'd recommend you start using ARC, it will make things a lot easier and actually faster too.

Comment: Is there any way to just disable ARC in the LLVM compiler? When I click Convert to Objective-C ARC... it says all targets already use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using the ASI (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) api, refer to this answer as it needs to be built using -fno-obj-arc flags for specific classes... [Files doesn't support the ARC feature, how to deal with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633903/files-doesnt-support-the-arc-feature-how-to-deal-with) and refer to the answer titled 'Disable ARC for that one class'