# Xcode ARC (automatic reference counting), "release is unavailable"

Tags: xcode, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

For my first time using Xcode I was following a [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_quick_start/010-Tutorial_Using_Xcode_to_Write_Hello_World/hello_world_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010575-CH2-SW1) online.
I did everything as the [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_quick_start/010-Tutorial_Using_Xcode_to_Write_Hello_World/hello_world_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010575-CH2-SW1) showed me, but I am afraid that it's too outdated.

The error I encounter is:

```
[font_attributes release];
```

> 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
>
> ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'

My knowledge on Cocoa and Xcode is limited, but I still wish to expand my learning.

How may I fix the `ARC` issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273341/under-automatic-reference-counting-why-are-retain-release-and-dealloc-not-all

Comment: This is caused by the current version of Xcode enabling Automatic Reference Counting for all new projects. ARC is new in Xcode 4.2 and older tutorials will assume you are using manual reference counting. The answer by @NJones has the fix.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Turn off ARC for this project.
    This is done by setting **'Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting'** to **NO** in the '*Build Settings*' tab of your target in the project page.

2) Remove all `retain` `release` `autorelease` `NSAutoReleasePools` and `retainCount` calls, since ARC makes them for you. With the exception of `NSAutoReleasePool`s They have been replaced by `@autorelease{}`.

The second option has been automated by apple [see this question to use the refactoring tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7164848/927947).

Comment: Regarding option #2, under the menu item Edit->Refactor there is an option to have XCode convert your project for you.

Comment: Alot simpler to joust remove ARC on specific files. (See my answer)

Answer (score 47):

The two options given by [NJones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927947/njones) are valid and effective ways of dealing with `ARC` incompatibility. However, you do have a third option. Disabling `ARC` for *specific* files.

Giving the flags `-fno-objc-arc` to your non `ARC` compatible compile sources affectively marks them as such upon compilation.

You can find your compile sources under `Targets` → `Your App` → `Build Phases` → `Compile Sources`.

Comment: Good one! Useful for building with third-party stuff that has no ARC +1

Comment: it's answer actual even in 2016 year.

Comment: This is the best answer!