# Way to fix "release is not available"

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having trouble with `release`, as I read is because I'm using Xcode 4.2. I tried the option: "Convert to Objective-C ARC" but it still fails:

> Xcode found 6 issues that prevent conversion from proceeding.  Fix all ARC readiness issues and try again.
>
> ```
> receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
> ```
>
> ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'

and:

> ```
> [receivedData release];
> ```
>
> "release is unavailable"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode ARC (automatic reference counting), "release is unavailable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236797/xcode-arc-automatic-reference-counting-release-is-unavailable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just use:

```
receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
// or
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

because the reference count operation under ARC is *automatic*.

Comment: perfect! what about the [receivedData release]; "release is unavailable"?

Comment: With ARC, you need no more retain, release and autorelease.