# Files doesn't support the ARC feature, how to deal with

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting

My project uses the ARC(Automatic Reference Counter), so when i try to import the ASIHTTPRequest library which has 4 classes that used in their implementation the autorelease statement, here is an example:

```
[self setAccessLock:[[[NSRecursiveLock alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

The error that i got:

```
ARC forbids explicit message send of autorelease
```

What should i do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have got the solution, i needed to add the right flags to the compiler flags for each file which doesn't support the ARC. For me, i use Xcode 4.2, so under `target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources`, double click on the file you want to disable the ARC feature and put `-fno-objc-arc` the click on `Done`. And it's Done ;)

Please note, that if the file doesn't exist on the list, you can just add it by clicking the + button and then perform the same work above.

Answer (score 9):

Disable ARC for that one class

When you migrate a project to use ARC, the -fobjc-arc compiler flag is set as the default for all Objective-C source files. You can disable ARC for a specific class using the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for that class.

In Xcode, in the target Build Phases tab, open the Compile Sources group to reveal the source file list. Double-click the file for which you want to set the flag, enter -fno-objc-arc in the pop-up panel, then click Done.